# Import custom package into python package

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a package, let's call it X (in a private gitlab repo).

I want to use that package inside other packages, for instance in package A.

This is the current setup.py of package A:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='A',
      version='0.1.0',
      description='Package A',
      author='me',
      url='a.com',
      license='Apache2',
      install_requires=[<A deps>],
      packages=['main', 'packageX'],
      include_package_data=True)
```

The closest I was able to archive was to setup X as a submodule of A so that A had the following structure:

```
.
├── package A
│   └── main
│      └── etc..
│   └── packageX (git submodule)
│      └── etc..
│      └── pyproject.toml
│   └── setup.py
```

With this, when I do `python3 -m build`, package X is included in the build and I'm able to use the library, although, dependencies of X are not automatically installed, thus I have to put them in the `install_requires` field (which I don't want to).

Ideally, I wanted to put X as an install_requires, since that would force all X's dependencies to be installed aswell, but I can't use direct references such as:

```
install_requires=[<A deps>, f'X @ file://localhost/{getcwd()}/packageX'],
```

because it is not distributable.

So ideally I would want to either use the package registry of gitlab with authentication or have a way to include all the dependencies automatically from the submodule.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing the concepts of a python package/module, a library made of diferente modules and a package dependencies.

By including the package X in the package A, the package A becomes a library made of diferente modules. Both are shipped at the same time and will be installed at the same time by a single setup.py.

"install_requires" is used to indicate packages/libraries which the 3rd party dependencies off your package. These are maintained elsewere and/or by other people. Also they will have their own dependencies and setup.py.

Further Reading:
https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Comment: I get that, package X is only inside package A because I could not get any other way to externally include package X.This is because X is not available on PyPI and I could not find a way to include the package from gitlab PyPI repository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).